# How does Moodle encrypts the password?

Tags: moodle

I'm developing a custom login application for Moodle.

I just want to know which algorithm does Moodle uses to encrypt passwords? So that, I can authenticate Moodle users on my login application.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the Moodle version. Until 2.5: MD5 plus optional salt (a global salt, for every password, stored in `$CFG->passwordsaltmain`). Since Moodle 2.5:

> From Moodle 2.5 onwards Moodle automatically generates and adds a different salt for each individual user.

And:

> The new password hashing mechanism relies on bcrypt support from PHP which is only normally available in PHP version is 5.3.7 or greater (see note below). If you are using a version of PHP which doesn't properly support bcrypt, Moodle will fall back to the old password hashing scheme, so we recommend that you continue to use a site-wide salt until you are able to upgrade PHP.

Source: [Password salting](http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/Password_salting).

Answer (score 2):

Moodle has a pluggable authentication architecture.  If you develop a custom [Moodle authentication plugin](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Authentication_plugins), or find one that has already been developed, you could pass *any* kind of authentication token to Moodle.

Comment: I don't want to connect to Moodle. I have got a database, I just want to encrypt user credentials and compare it with my database, for checking user access.

Comment: So, you want to use Moodle as an authentication _provider_? I suppose that's possible, but that would be a very weird architecture.  Do things properly by using [LDAP as a user database](http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/LDAP_authentication), then configure both Moodle and your application to authenticate against LDAP.

Comment: I am developing a login page in PHP. As soon as user submits their credentials, my application should send an AJAX request to verify, whether the login credentials are correct or not. I have access to PHPMyAdmin. I just want to know how to encrypt user entered password or any other way to check whether the user entered values are correct or not?

Answer (score 2):

After searching a while for the password hash generating function I found the following simple answer: in newer versions of Moodle you can use the following:

```
echo password_hash( "my password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT, array() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Latest Moodle uses password_hash(), see more detailed answer on Moodle's forums: https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=235504#p1023177

Answer (score -1):

Moodle use MD5 algorithm to encrypt passwords